# PHP str_replace with function

Tags: php, str-replace

Is it possible use `str_replace()` and use function in replace?

```
$value = "gal($data)";

$replace = str_replace($dat, $value, $string);
```

**`gal($data)`** is a function and I need replace one code for this function and show, but the script only give me finally this **`gal($data)`**, and the function no show nothing

Is it possible use `str_replace()` for replace code and replace by the function or some similar method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHP has a function called [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) that does this. When you pass it a callback function, it will pass each match through your function. You can choose to replace, based upon the matched value, or ignore it.

As an example, suppose I have a pattern that matches various strings, such as `[a-z]+`. I may not want to replace every instance with the same value, so I can call a function upon eat match found, and determine how I ought to respond:

```php
function callback ($match) {
    if ($match[0] === "Jonathan")
        return "Superman";
    return $match[0];
}

$subject = "This is about Jonathan.";
$pattern = "/[a-z]+/i";
$results = preg_replace_callback($pattern, "callback", $subject);

// This is about Superman.
echo $results;
```

Note in our callback function how I am able to return special values for certain matches, and not all matches.

#### Expanding Abbreviations

Another example would be a lookup. Suppose we wanted to find abbreviations of programming languages, and replace them with their full titles. We may have an array that has abbreviations as keys, with long-names as values. We could then use our callback ability to lookup the full-length names:

```php
function lookup ($match) {
    $langs = Array(
        "JS"  => "JavaScript", 
        "CSS" => "Cascading Style Sheets", 
        "JSP" => "Java Server Pages"
    );
    return $langs[$match[0]] ?: $match[0];
}

$subject = "Does anybody know JS? Or CSS maybe? What about PHP?";
$pattern = "/(js|css|jsp)/i";
$results = preg_replace_callback($pattern, "lookup", $subject);

// Does anybody know JavaScript? Or Cascading Style Sheets maybe? What about PHP?
echo $results;
```

So every time our regular expression finds a match, it passes the match through `lookup`, and we can return the appropriate value, or the original value.

Comment: I don´t know that function you can tell me how use it in this case , thank´s for your help

Comment: @user1851816 Perhaps I'm confused about what it is you're asking. The function I suggested will let you perform string replacement via a callable function. This lets you add a bit more logic into how you will replace, when you will replace, and with what you will replace as opposed to straight-forward 1:1 string replacement.

Comment: It´s simple if you can tell me how modificate the code perfect i try this 3 days ago and no get this point for works fine , thank´s for all

Comment: Thank´s foor your help , i understand how works the function now , thank´s for all and for your time , regards !